# what's wrong with using 'javascript:history.go(-1)'?

Tags: javascript, browser

came across some twitter banter about how terrible it is to use

```
javascript:history.go(-1)
```

of course without any hints as to why.

If it's so terrible, why? What's the alternative? (besides history.back(), which seems to do exact same thing). Is it a matter of cross browser compatibility?

For example, I've seen it used on an error page to let users try to "go back" using the above.

I've tried google, but an no avail, in regards to why it'd be so horrible to use. Any pointers/explanations would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The page doesn't reload on history back which I have found to be problematic on some pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They may have been referring to use of the pseudo protocol `javascript:`, which generally means this is an anchor's `href` attribute, which is ugly. It is not a real link, and with JavaScript disabled, it'll do nothing whilst looking like a functional link. I think the only valid use for this *protocol* is for bookmarklets.

Also, as [Russell Dias points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113343/whats-wrong-with-using-javascripthistory-go-1/5113397#5113397), it does exactly the same as the back button, so what is the point of having it? Should we have a reload button too that calls `window.location.reload()` ?

Comment: Interesting. One example where required: User on product search results page uses form filters that changes the display of their results. These filters update the querystring. User clicks on a product - on that product page there is a 'back to results' link. The JS method will put the user back on the page with the correct querystring for their results, a hardcoded link wont.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head. I believe that this javascript simulates the browser back button. One can never be too sure as to how a user got to a certain page, that is to say, they could have got to the page via an external site. Therfore this implementation would simply, send them back, which might not be a desirable result.

Comment: sure, but what if that is the intended behavior, as in my error page example?

Comment: @andryuha: honestly, if that's indented behavior I can't see anything wrong with it. I've seen some big sites use it, albeit sparingly.